# Joining property values of objects in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. The objects have a property called `userName`. Is there a way to concatenate the `userName` values into a comma delimited string? I assume I can use the `join` function but the only way I can think of takes two steps.

```
var userNames: string[];
objectArr.forEach((o) => { userNames.push(o.userName); });
var userNamesJoined = userNames.join(",");
```

Is there a way to do it in one line of code?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach` and drop the parenthesis and the curly braces in the lambda:

`var userNames = objectArr.map(o => o.userName).join(', ');`

Comment: what shoud we do if we don't want to join the empty usernames ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil just filter the items before joining:

`objectArr.map(o => o.userName).filter(name => name).join(', ');`

Comment: Can we collect more than 1 properties? Like fullName?